# Nested layout in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm making a site that has a header/footer common to every page, but the page content has different layouts with completely different `<head>` sections and stylesheets. How can I render a template within another template so that it's a completely independent section - it doesn't inherit any of the parent's styles and also doesn't affect the parent?

I've tried doing <%= render template: 'layouts/test' %>, but the stylesheets overlap.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what you need is partials. You can separate them into different components and use rails partial.

For example, if you always have the same header and footer, you can put them in your `layouts/application.html.erb` file. Then in each page's body template, you can render each individual section using partial.

Just create a file like this `_seciont_1.html.erb`. Then in your corresponding page, render it using `<%= render partial: "section_1" %>`. More info check this link below.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

```
------------------------------
|           header           |
------------------------------
|         |                  |
|section_1|     section_2    |
|         |                  |
------------------------------
|           footer           |
------------------------------
```

As for style sheets, in your `application.css` or `application.scss` file, (live under `app/assets/stylesheets/`), remove the line `*= require_tree .`. This line is the one that loads all your style sheets. Instead, only pick the ones that you use across all pages, e.g. css file for footer and header.

Then in each particular partial file, load the corresponding css file like this.

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'section_1', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`

Do the same for your JS files. You can find it in your `application.js` which lives in `app/assets/javascript/`. Remove the line `//= require_tree .` And require the corresponding js file using this.

`<%= javascript_include_tag 'section_1', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `iframe`. Iframes are basically separate HTML documents with their own stylesheets etc. The trouble is they parent page won't really be aware of the child page's size, so you'll need to either pick a width and be happy with an inner scroll bar, or do javascript.

A better solution might be to work out a better way to manage your CSS so that you're not doing things that affect things they shouldn't. It's generally something that will come round to bite you a lot as your software grows. There's lots of ways to do that, but from a personal point of view, I'm a big fan of the BEM syntax.

There's a good [overview here](http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/) - remember though, it's  go to work for *you*, so do not take what different developers do as gospel!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm new to web development and know little about iframes, so I'll check out that + BEM. Basically, I have a working website with a separate "how it works" page where I want to include the header and footer but have a different single-page-layout which I purchased online. That's the reason why the stylesheets overlap.